# Monit configuration for postgres

Tags: postgresql, monit

I am trying to use monit on my postgres. My monit configuration file is

> check process postgresql with pidfile /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/postmaster.pid
>
> > start program = "/etc/init.d/postgresql start"
> >      stop program = "/etc/init.d/postgresql stop"
> >      if failed unixsocket /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432 protocol pgsql 
> >          then restart
> >      if failed host localhost port 5432 protocol pgsql then restart
> >      if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout`

When i run `cat /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main/postmaster.pid`. The result is

> 10271
>   /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main
>   1418738148
>   5432
>   /var/run/postgresql
>   localhost
>    5432001    720899

But my monit would not restart the postgres. I am referring to http://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/ConfigurationExamples#postgresql.

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try choosing either the UNIX or TCP/IP protocol. I'd go for the UNIX connection, and remove or comment out the second if statement...

`if failed host localhost port 5432 protocol pgsql then restart`

Comment: Thank you for reply, I will try and let you know